# Magento 1 get list of all attributes with specific value

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, script

I want to get a list of all attributes that do have the value `Used in Product Listing` and `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` set to Yes.

How can I easliy get all attributes with this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$readConnection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$query = $readConnection->select()
    ->from($this->getResource()->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute'))
    ->where('used_in_product_listing = ?', 1)
    ->where('used_for_sort_by = ?', 1);
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

**$results** will be array of database rows

If you need **attribute_code** you should join that with **eav_attribute** table, using **attribute_id** field

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code,you can easily get all attributes with specific value.

```
$productAttrs = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
$productAttrs->addFieldToFilter('used_in_product_listing',1);
$productAttrs->addFieldToFilter('used_for_sort_by',1);
foreach($productAttrs as $_attr)
{
    echo $_attr->getAttributeId()."-".$_attr->getAttributeCode();
    ...........
    ...........
}
```

This is one of the easiest way to get all details about each attribute.